# Rails: Order dom elements created by two different each loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, loops

I have two each loops inside `week` loop, `static_events, loop_events` creates links that sorted by time.
The problem is when the first loop ends, the second each loop create elements after the first one, and the order breaks.

```
<% @week.each do |day| %>

   <% @static_events.each do |event| %>
      <%= link_to event.start_time.strftime('%H:%M'), event_path(event.id) %>
   <% end %>

   <% @loop_events.each do |event| %>
      <%= link_to event.start_time.strftime('%H:%M'), event_path(event.id) %>
   <% end %>

<% end %>
```

The result will be roughly as:

```
01:00     # =>  @static_events => index 1
03:00     # =>  @static_events => index 2
04:00     # =>  @static_events => index 3
02:00     # =>  @loop_events => index 1
```

I need this result:

```
01:00     # =>  @static_events => index 1
02:00     # =>  @loop_events => index 1
03:00     # =>  @static_events => index 2
04:00     # =>  @static_events => index 3
```

How can I order/sort both each loops by time, and achieve the result above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can merge them (*arrays, not loops, of course*) and sort by time:

```
<% [@static_events, @loop_events].flatten.sort_by(&:start_time).each do |event| %>
  <%= link_to event.start_time.strftime('%H:%M'), event_path(event.id) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Also consider doing this in the controller

Comment: Why not `(a + b).sort_by` instead of `[ a, b ].flatten.sort_by`?